# I have a mongodb JSON data and I want to find the exact match word “Approved”

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongodb data and I want to find the exact match word "Approved" in Array named "Sales.Action".

But the array contains also other values other then the value "Approve" which also return when i query.

I want only one action to return.

```
{
"Sales" : [
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approved"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/20/2020 42:04:04"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approve",
            "Decline",
            "Edit",
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/20/2020 42:04:04"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approve",
            "Decline",
            "Edit",
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/21/2020 412:04:04"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approve",
            "Decline",
            "Edit",
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/21/2020 412:04:04"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            "Approve",
            "Decline",
            "Edit",
            "Remarks"
        ],
        "Log" : [
            "Created on: 04/23/2020 44:04:04"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

But I need to return only 1 value that is Approved.

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

### Find (Workaround)

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  from the query results to contain only the **first** element matching the query document.

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj.*S*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)

```
db.collection.find({ "Sales.Action": "Approved" }, { "Sales.Action.$": 1 })
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DdrHYagBPBO)

### Aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    Sales: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$Sales",
        cond: {
          $in: [
            "Approved",
            "$$this.Action"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4oN94KjG6Sz)

Comment: Try using find. Not aggregate.

Comment: @PawanKumar Find projection is limited, check if given workaround works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `filter` operator. I have considered that the collection's name is `sales`.

```
db.sales.aggregate({
    $project: {
    Sales: {
        $filter: {
            input:'$Sales', as: 'sales', cond: {$eq: ['$$sales.Action', ['Approved']]}}
        }
    }
}).pretty()
```

The output of the above was:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea47a863873d6e16c0f7aac"),
    "Sales" : [
        {
            "Action" : [
                "Approved"
            ],
            "Log" : [
                "Created on: 04/20/2020 42:04:04"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Pawan Kumar, did this help you?

Comment: @PawanKumar, as could you give a solid reason why you need `find` query instead of `aggregate`?